# get outerHeight of class and take the biggest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outerheight

I use `.outerHeight` to set the height of another div, using a class as selector.

```
var $example = $('.example');
var $height = $example.outerHeight();
var $styles = { 'height': $height }
$('.wrapper_sub').css($styles);
```

I want to use this on multiple "slides" of my site:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="example">Some Content</div>
  <div class="wrapper_sub">Other Content</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="example">Some Content</div>
  <div class="wrapper_sub">Other Content</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="example">Some Content</div>
  <div class="wrapper_sub">Other Content</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `.outerHeight` of every `.example`, take only the *highest value* and append this to all `.wrapper_sub` divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See comments inline:**

```
var maxHeight = 0; // Initialize to zero
var $example = $('.example'); // Cache to improve performance

$example.each(function() { // Loop over all the elements having class example

    // Get the max height of elements and save in maxHeight variable
    maxHeight = parseFloat($(this).outerHeight()) > maxHeight ? parseFloat($(this).outerHeight()) : maxHeight;
});

$('.wrapper_sub').height(maxHeight); // Set max height to all example elements
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/05hpapnq/1/)

Comment: Am I able to use a variable to improve the performance for `.example`, or does this cache only one element, and not every class it finds?

Comment: I would love to mark your answer as the correct one, but you need to "correct" it to fit my answer (for the google record).
I need to get the max height of `.example` and apply this value to every `.wrapper_sub` on page.

Comment: @MarianRick Didn't get you

Comment: I am able to understand and use your code, thats great. But in my question I do not want to apply the max-height of `.example` to all the other `.example` divs, I want to apply it to the `.wrapper_sub` divs. I have made an edit to your answer to fit as solution to my question! ;) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the `.example` elements and get the max value. Then apply this value to those elements:

```
//Set an empty array
var arr = [];

//Loop through the elements
$('.example').each(function() {
   //Push each value into the array
   arr.push(parseFloat($(this).outerHeight()));
});

//Get the max value with sort function
var maxH = arr.sort(function(a,b) { return b-a })[0];

//Apply the max value to the '.example' elements
$('.example').css({'height': maxH + 'px'});
```

Comment: just code is not enough for the OP, explain what you are doing